# How do you subtract from a datetime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I'd like to write a simple function to say in hours:

**How much time has passed since this has been created?**

My attempts:

```
-time = DateTime.now.hour - (self.created_at.hour)
```

Does anyone know how to do this in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: That won't work because you are only comparing hours, so if more than a day passes it will be inaccurate, but otherwise it should still compute to a number. Instead you could do `DateTime.now - self.created_at` directly, which will give you the time difference in seconds. What do you need to do?

Comment: That doesn't work because you can't subtract from DateTime unless its a string. And if it's a string, how do you display it as a time again

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Rails usually uses `Time`, not `DateTime`. Why don't you do `Time.now - self.created_at`? Then you can convert from seconds to hours by dividing by 3600.

Answer (score 19):

Got it!. First you have to make sure your data is in the same data it will be subtracted from whether its a Time or a DateTime. I chose time. Then you divide it by Ruby's built in time methods. This translates into how many days, but it can also be, 1.hour. etc.

```
(Time.now - self.created_at.to_time)/1.day
```

Answer (score 9):

You are looking for the time_ago_in_words(from_time, include_seconds = false) function. Here are some examples from the docs:

```
time_ago_in_words(3.minutes.from_now)       # => 3 minutes
time_ago_in_words(Time.now - 15.hours)      # => 15 hours
time_ago_in_words(Time.now)                 # => less than a minute
from_time = Time.now - 3.days - 14.minutes - 25.seconds     # => 3 days
```

Comment: I'm not looking for words. I'm looking on how to subtract a DateTime from another DateTime